# Word for "action requiring permission"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for this? For example, smartphone apps ask you permission to do various things: using the camera is a _____

**Update 2019-01-21**

One suggestion is *privilege*, which is good, but not quite what I'm going for.

What I'm looking for: In order to do X, you must be granted *privilege*. This means that X is a *[word]*

It might be correct to say "doing X is a privilege", but not "X itself is a privilege"

Answer (score 2):

The word typically used in this context is **privilege**. Here are some examples:

> Camera don’t even show up in mine at all. None the less the audio section showing. You got background app refresh turned on? Might be some app that has camera privileges and is stepping far beyond the means of what is says it does. Try revoking camera privileges to certain apps and definitely report that to Apple and check back here if you figure it out.
>   <sub>[[Question] Has anyone experienced camera audio running in the background? I can’t seem to stop it no matter what I do.](https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSBeta/comments/6xphtr/question_has_anyone_experienced_camera_audio/)</sub>

> If the app targets Android 8.0 (API level 26), the system grants only `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` at that time; however, if the app later requests `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, the system immediately grants that privilege without prompting the user.
>   <sub>[Android 8.0 Behavior Changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes)</sub>

> Check your microphone and you'll find any apps that have access to it. You can revoke all of their microphone privileges if you want.
>   <sub>[Your Phone Is Probably Listening. Here's How To Put It On Mute](https://www.wfmynews2.com/article/news/local/2-wants-to-know/your-phone-is-probably-listening-heres-how-to-put-it-on-mute/83-552022008)</sub>

Comment: This is very close, but not quite what I had in mind. See my update. Vis à vis your second example, `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is the _privilege_, but external writes themselves are not _privileges_, at least in the sense that I'm going for

(Thank you for the answer)